# Tinyxml Set Attribute

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have not idea what I am doing wrong. I am writing a simple program in C++ to edit a xml config file using TinyXml.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <video>
        <fps state="notlimited">
            <limit value="60" />
        </fps>
    </video>
</config>
```

Here is the section of code that edits the file:

```
if ( limitFPS )
    {
        cout << "Enter the FPS limit:" << endl;

        cin >> fpsLimit;

        TiXmlElement *fpsState = hConfig.FirstChildElement( "config" ).FirstChildElement( "video" ).FirstChildElement( "fps" ).ToElement();
        fpsState->SetAttribute("state", "limited");

        TiXmlElement *fpsLimitElement = hConfig.FirstChildElement( "config" ).FirstChildElement( "video" ).FirstChildElement( "fps" ).FirstChildElement( "limit" ).ToElement();
        fpsLimitElement->SetAttribute( "value", fpsLimit );
    }
```

If the user has said that they want to limit the fps then the attribute "state" for tag fps is change to limited. Then the attribute "value" for the limit is set to the fps level the user has specified.

However when I run the program it dose not change the specified attributes. I have looked over my code and can not find any errors in it. Also I am not getting any errors.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you making sure to write out the XML file afterwards? From your code snippet it doesn't show that.

Comment: I used .SaveFile() and it worked. Thanks for pointing my in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.SaveFile()](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html) saves changes to the xml document